# Treating a compound word as a discrete word in FxCop

Tags: fxcop

Using the word 'MicroTep' in a string fires rule CA1703 because FxCop doesn't recognize 'Tep'. I want FxCop to treat 'MicroTep' as a single word. I couldn't solve this by adding 'MicroTep' to one of the dictionaries and I don't want to add just 'Tep'. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there simply isn't any way to do this without adding "tep" to the dictionary.  If you're curious for the reasons for this, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/d63b9cad-1133-403c-bdb4-526263d4b55d.

If adding "tep" to the dictionary isn't acceptable, the only other feasible option would be to suppress the violations individually (assuming that you want to keep the rule enabled).

Comment: Ok, thanks! Seems like this won't change since the post is from 2007. :/

Comment: The same tokenization logic still seems to be applied by VS 2012 code analysis, and I'm guessing that changing this behaviour is unlikely to ever be seen as particularly high priority for the product team...